# Make grub boot on default without waiting

Tags: linux, grub2, startup, boot-loader

I would like grub(2) to boot on my main os without waiting. Every single time I start my computer, I either have to press `<Enter>` or wait for ten second.
Is it possible for grub to boot directly without any prompt into my default OS ? And if yes how ?

For information, I have linux mint with the cinnamon desktop.

An here is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In your `/etc/default/grub`, you should uncomment `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and should set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` to `true` as in:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

If from then on you need access to the GRUB menu at boot time, press SHIFT after the BIOS finishes the boot process, but before the hard drive is used, and keep it pressed until GRUB appears.

> ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’
>
> Wait this many seconds before displaying the
>   menu. If ESC is pressed during that time, display the menu and wait
>   for input according to ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’. If a hotkey associated with a
>   menu entry is pressed, boot the associated menu entry immediately. If
>   the timeout expires before either of these happens, display the menu
>   for the number of seconds specified in ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’ before booting
>   the default entry.
>
> If you set ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’, you should also set ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT=0’
>   so that the menu is not displayed at all unless ESC is pressed.
>
> This option is unset by default, and is deprecated in favour of the
>   less confusing ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown’ or
>   ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden’.
>
> ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET’
>
> In conjunction with ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’,
>   set this to ‘true’ to suppress the verbose countdown while waiting for
>   a key to be pressed before displaying the menu.
>
> This option is unset by default, and is deprecated in favour of the
>   less confusing ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown’.

Comment: It does't work for some reasons. I have tried this in the past. I tried again and it doesn't work.

Comment: @NilsANDRÉ-CHANG What happens if you also take out the splash from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` ? It may be unrelated, I would give it a try.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" is on by default.

Comment: I sugested taking out the `splash` word

Comment: On Ubuntu this doesn't work because it will "helpfully" reset the timeout to 10 if you set it to zero. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/268744/grub-hidden-menu-not-working, https://askubuntu.com/questions/469347/how-to-hide-grub-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one OS, it's probably because of that. Try adding these lines into your GRUB file and updating GRUB.

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

It worked for me. For reasons of adding these lines check out my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993420/why-wont-grub-boot-immediately-into-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

If the solutions from here didn't work there is another solution.
The second os must be installed in full on a separate device with boot partition.
On the first os set:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Unplug the other os hardware from the machine.
Run `update-grub2`.
Plug it back.
Grub will boot on default without waiting. The second os will have the entrance via bios setup only.